# Updating multiple Spritekit nodes with the same name

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

I am currently making a game with Spritekit & Swift3 for the first time; it is a 2D, side-scrolling endless runner. I'm trying to have certain nodes move with my camera, but the problem is that they will be procedurally generated, belonging to the same class, so I need them all to have the same name. Here's the relevant sections of code, before I go any further:

(All variables have been initialized)

//move these nodes with the camera

```
private var ChoosePieces: ChoosePiecesClass?;

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        initializeGame();
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ChoosePieces") {
        node, stop in
        _ = node as! SKSpriteNode

        self.ChoosePieces?.moveWithCamera();

    }
}

private func initializeGame() {
    ChoosePieces = childNode(withName: "ChoosePieces") as? ChoosePiecesClass;
}
```

I have tested the moveWithCamera() function and it works well--it simply increments the node's x-value by 10, moving at the same pace as the camera so that the node remains on screen at the same location.

My problem is that I'm not exactly sure how to use enumerateChildNodes(withName: "String") with my nodes, so that it will recognize all of them and move them. Right now the pieces just stay still. I found out about this function from another person's post--he/she was trying to spawn "enemies" in his/her game. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing with? If you want to enumerate all the nodes with a specific name, just give them the same name, and enumerate through them appropriately based on their parent(s).

Comment: Take a look at advanced search : https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode#1654468 Also, make sure that self.ChoosePieces is not nil, and it has an expected value...

Comment: Hi there, sorry that I wasn't clear enough, I am new to this. So the problem is that the project builds fine, but the nodes with the name "ChoosePieces" do not move at all. For testing purposes, I have manually placed 5 nodes all called "ChoosePieces" in the same SKScene. I am sure that I have written the enumerate function incorrectly, but I do not know how or where.

Comment: As I said, check if everything is executing (put a break point and inspect values). If I find time later, I will write an example for you, but simple debugging will show what is the error.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will attempt to debug it with break points as soon as time allows and report back here with the results, if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you show what moveWithCamera() method does?

Comment: Of course: 
`func moveWithCamera() {
        self.position.x += 10;
    }`
That's all it has. I've since attempted to debug with breakpoints, and have made some "progress." I noticed that I declared the nodes as the wrong class in my scene, so I fixed it so that they are all of type ChoosePiecesClass. Now, only one of the pieces moves--the left-most piece on the scene--and it moves extremely quickly, easily outrunning the camera.

Comment: Just look at Steve's answer. If you want to move nodes, then use 'node' variable inside of a block you are already using. Currently you are running moving action on the single node (self.ChoosePieces) Also you probably want to downcast a 'node' to a ChoosePiecesClass so you can use its moveWithCamera() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually with `enumerateChildNodes` you do something with the node that is returned e.g. modifying your own example:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ChoosePieces") {
        node, stop in
        if let piece = node as? SKSpriteNode { // Cast to Sprite if we can
            piece.moveWithCamera()
        }
    }
}
```

So for every `node` that is returned, we cast it to a new SKSpriteNode called 'piece (if we can - using the `as?` operator - because `enumerateChildNodes` returns SKNodes) ' and then call `moveWithCamera` on the 'piece' node.

(the line `piece.moveWithCamera()` I made up - your original code appeared to be calling a class method(?) to do something. You might want `self.moveWithCamera(piece)` etc)

In your code, you did nothing with the nodes returned by your enumeration.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help! I tried this, but I got an error on the line containing `if let piece = node as! SKSpriteNode` that says Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not SKSpriteNode.

Comment: Just change as! To as? @Ardemis

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed response. This worked well, thanks for all the help guys!